# Why lazy property and didSet will end up with recursion call?

Tags: ios, swift

The below code works just fine

```
class A {

    var s: MyStruct! {
        didSet {
            print("didSet")
            print(n)
        }
    }

    lazy var n: Int = s.x + 1

    func viewDidLoad() {
        s = MyStruct()
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
    var x = 1
    init() { print("MyStruct init") }
}

let a = A()
a.viewDidLoad()
```

with output :

```
MyStruct init
didSet
2
```

---

However, if we have lazy properties as follow

```
class A {

    var s: MyStruct! {
        didSet {
            print("didSet")
            print(n)
        }
    }

    lazy var n: Int = s.x + 1

    func viewDidLoad() {
        s = MyStruct()
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
    lazy var x = 1
    init() { print("MyStruct init") }
}

let a = A()
a.viewDidLoad()
```

It will end up with endless recursion call

```
MyStruct init
didSet
didSet
didSet
...
```

Why lazy property and didSet will end up with recursion call?

Comment: lazy vars on structs should be used very carefully or not at all.

Comment: Accessing `x` on MyStruct is a mutating operation (`mutating get`) so this triggers the `didSet` for the property `s`.  So the infinite loop is `print(n)` -> get `s.x`-> call `s.didSet` -> `print(n)`-> ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a `lazy stored` property. When the struct is initialized with `MyStruct()`, there's no value stored in `MyStruct.x`.

It will only be populated when it is accessed first time. When a property is changed, a value type like `struct MyStruct` is considered to be changed as well - so it's `didSet` is invoked (again) upon first access of `x`.

Here's how it becomes infinite loop.

1. `viewDidLoad() > A.s.setter > A.s.didset` [Expected]
2. First access of `A.n.getter` for the `print(n)` part.
3. `s.x` is **lazy stored** and upon first value population (update), it triggers - `A.s.modify > A.s.didset` & we land again at `A.n.getter`.
4. It loops indefinitely between `2` & `3` after this.

See screenshot -
[image]

Comment: I still don't understand. By the third time we land on `n.getter`, why do we reach `s.modify`? At that point, value of `n` should be known already (`s.x` should be initialised to 1 by then). Can't it just return that, without getting `s.x`?

Comment: In the screenshot `Frame 11` hasn't completed executing - value of `n` was NOT received for `print(n)` part and somehow we managed to land again at the same place. We can easily break this loop by delaying the call for `print(n)` by `0.1 seconds` or so. As long as it is synchronous, it will behave this way.